# DiscordAPIError Invalid Form Body when Trying to Purge Messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I was pretty sure that this code worked correctly at one point, but recently it was brought to my attention that it sometimes works but not always (read: It will *always* purge my messages by n amount, but it *might* not purge another members).

Because I was teaching myself how to use multiple files on this project, the code is actually split between two files. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the issue or not. Given the size of the two files, I've uploaded them both to pastebin.

[The command code.](https://pastebin.com/zK3ibvMy)
[The Function code.](https://pastebin.com/JnYR8szg)

It purges just fine when I try and purge n where n is any number within the acceptable range, but when I try and purge n by username I get an error message stating

> DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
>
> limit: Value "" is not int.

**(note that is two double quotes, the formatting is a little unclear)**

I'm confused as to where it is getting a value that is not an int, as I'm running the amount through praseInt. I've snipped out the code segment that checks if a user is defined and posted it below as I believe it to be the problem:

```
if (user) { // If User is Provided
  debug.run(`Filtering messages by ${user.username}`);
  const filterBy = user ? user.id : client.user.id;
  messages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === filterBy).array().slice(0, amount);
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I'm more or less about to scrap the user feature if I can't figure it out.

Also I apologize for the formatting. I can never get the hang of this sites formatting.

Comment: Just to make sure it's not your `amount` variable, could you try to overwrite the value in the function by setting `amount = 5`. Beside that I would tend to say that it may be an issue in the discord.js library. In my oppinion it is supposed to validate your input before sending it to the Discord api. You can contact the devs and their help team via Discord. You usually get a response very quickly.

Comment: I hard coded it to a number of different amounts. Sometimes it would work, sometimes it wouldn't. The results would very depending on the number I wanted to try and delete, as well as the member that I was trying to target for deleting.

I will reach out to them I guess. I just wanted to check and make sure it wasn't an error on my part first.

Comment: Do you mind telling us what version of discord.js you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of
`.array().slice(0, amount)`.

The array of fetched messages doesn't need to be cut by the `amount` variable if the `message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: amount }).then((messages) => {` line already limits it.